# CGPointApplyAffineTransform giving negative values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I have a CGPointApplyAffine which is giving me negative values such as -161 for x and -58 for y.
Are these values possible? Or am I using it incorrectly?

```
CGPoint rotatedCenter = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(subview.center, self.transform);
```

Thanks!

Comment: In general negative values are absolutely possible. What exactly transform you apply to the point?

Comment: I'm rotating an image with subviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absoulutley.

Lame example:

Say you had a dot located at 100,100 and you rotated the image (centered at 0,0) 180 degrees.

The dot would now be at -100,-100.